# Fetch records based on smallest datetime among multiple datetime fields

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

```
id | name |       reqdt1        |        indt2        |      outdt3
---|------|---------------------|---------------------|--------------------
1  | A    | 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 2020-02-02 00:00:00 | 2020-02-02 00:00:00
2  | B    |                     | 2020-02-02 00:00:00 | 
3  | C    | 2020-12-02 00:00:00 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00
4  | D    |                     | 2021-03-02 00:00:00 | 2021-05-02 00:00:00
```

I have the above structure of a table. So the table consists of the list of documents which the user will insert and each document has 3 datetime fields

1. `reqdt`, the date on which the document was requested,
2. `indt`, the date on which the document was accepted by the user and
3. `outdt`, the date on which the document was again sent back.

So now I'm trying to write a query such that, the user will input the year, let's say for example the year input is `2019`. So I want the row with `id = 1` to be displayed.

If the user input is `2020`, row with `id with 2,3` should be displayed.

if the year is `2021`, row with `id = 4` should be displayed.

I mean to say the rows should be displayed in the year having the smallest date , ex for `id = 1` the date includes both year '2019' and '2020', so it should get displayed only when the user input is '2019' and not get displayed for the year '2020'. Ho do I write query for the above problem statement

Comment: All your table fields has values like `2021-05-02 00:00:00`, so better change it to data type `DATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`LEAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least).

> **`LEAST`** With two or more arguments, returns the smallest (minimum-valued) argument

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE YEAR(LEAST(reqdt1, indt2, outdt3)) = 2020;
```

Make sure you take care of `NULL` values. In that case you can modify query in following manner(make null value as max supported year by date `9999`).

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE YEAR(LEAST(IFNULL(reqdt1, '9999'), IFNULL(indt2, '9999'), IFNULL(outdt3, '9999'))) = 2020;
```